# How to redirect particular Internet Service Providers away from my website

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services

I'd like to redirect particular Internet Service Providers to other websites when trying to access my website (I'm a html/css newbie).

I'm not sure how to do this or whether it is possible with html/css(?), should I be looking at another language or is there a setting in Amazon Web Services that allows me to block or redirect specified ISPs.

Any ideas are very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "particular Internet Service Providers"? Do you mean if a person has their Internet connection provided by a particular company, then you want to redirect them to a different website? Or are you referring to which webpage the user was viewing when they clicked a link to go to your website? (Oh, and can I ask why do you wish to do this?)

Comment: You got it the first time :)

I have an issue with a company that's taking liberties, they've been my website everyday for the past month and I guess it's some malignant recruitment stalking or something of the that nature and not just blatantly ripping off content.

Their ISP registers on Google Analytics as "company name" so I figured I'd be able to filter viewers in the manner of:

if(isp != "company name")
{
   GoToHomePage();
}
else
{
  RedirectToOtherWebsite();
}


But I've never dealt with ISP data and haven't a clue how to access it, or which language to do it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reminded of a story where a competitor visited a company's website to scrape pricing information. So, the company changed their website to show different prices to their competitor!

So, it seems your goal is *"when requests come from IP address XX, don't give them access to my website"*.

Here's a few ways to achieve this:

- [Block traffic from a single IP](http://chopmo.dk/posts/2015/06/13/blocking-traffic-in-aws.html) using Network Access Control Lists (NACLs) — very simple and effective!
- Or, you can configure rules using [Advanced Request Routing for AWS Application Load Balancers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/)
- Or, you could [use AWS Web Application Firewall (WAF)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/web-acl-ip-conditions.html) to block specific IP addresses

I think it would be more fun to send them to an alternative website with false information, so they don't realise you are actually blocking them!!

Comment: Second using NACL

Comment: John, you're a star! Thank you so much for helping me with this :)

Answer (score 0):

I reread your issue and you only wanted specific providers, this would redirect for everyone. this wont work if popups are disabled

```
<html>
<body onload = "forwardFunction()">

<script type="text/javascript">

function forwardFunction() {
  window.open("https://www.google.com","_self");
}


</script>


If you can read this something went wrong.
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path :) I'll need to dig a little further into how to filter ISPs by string.